# unable to execue the following select statement getting error

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-like

when i execute the following select statement i am getting the below error.

I am trying to execute the below statement in Oracle server 9.1.

I believe due to this i am getting this error.

I know we can excute the query for single quotes by '%Blondeau D''Uva%'. But i am looking for query which will pass the special character value as parameter.

Kindluy let me know how to escape single quotes in old oracle server

ERROR :

```
  ORA-00933: SQL Command not properly ended
Error at line : 1 Column : 50
```

Query:

```
Select * FROM TABLEA where UI_FNAME like q'[%Michael%]' and UI_LNAME  like q'[ %Blondeau D'Uva%]';
```

Comment: `WHERE WHERE`...

Comment: what is your question exactly? The fix to your code is using double quote and delete the second where. What do you mean pass the special char as a parameter? And what does this has to do with the code you posted?

Comment: or do you search for something like `'D'||unistr('\C2AD')||'Uva'`?

Comment: No Still its not working.. Its working fine in other sql server but not for this server. Oracle version for the server i am facing the issue is 9.2.0.8.0

Comment: By 'server' do you mean 'database'?

Answer (score 0):

On oracle the following should work

```
Select * 
FROM   TABLEA 
where  UI_FNAME like '[%Michael%]' 
and    UI_LNAME like '[ %Blondeau D''Uva%]';
```

So no duplicate where
And you have to quote the ' between D und Uva
And probably the q before the ' is wrong ... so I have removed it as well.

Ok tried it out with the q operator:

```
Select * 
FROM   employees 
where  first_name like q'[%Michael%]' 
and last_name  like q'[ %Blondeau D'Uva%]';
```

No errors no row ...

Comment: The `q` seems to be an Oracle specific literal. Something with special quotation handling.

Comment: Ok funny .. something new for me ... https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html

Comment: This was the first time for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Two things about your query:

1. Two times usage of `where` where there should be just one.
2. About the second condition. You have used `q'[ %Blondeau D'Uva%]'` in `like` clause. I think that won't give you the result you might be looking for. This has nothing to do with your error, but still, it would not hurt to re-check the query.

Try this, this shouldn't run you into any error :

```
Select * FROM TABLEA 
 where UI_FNAME like q'[%Michael%]' 
   and UI_LNAME like q'[%Blondeau D'Uva%]';
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As others have tried to give you an answer, but I think you probably need to keep `%` outside brackets -

```
Select * 
FROM   TABLEA 
where  UI_FNAME like '%[Michael]%' 
and    UI_LNAME like '%[ Blondeau D''Uva]%';
```